# Android remote or push configuration profile

Tags: android, api, email, configuration, mdm

I am searching a solution to configure an Android mail account from a Web URL/link.

The Android Device Administration API (since 2.2) is very restrictive and does not include mail account configuration.

On iOS, there is configuration profile system. You just have to download it to configure your iOS device but what is the good way to do with Android devices ?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution ?

Comment: Has anything changed with Android since this question?  I am looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like configuration profile on Android. The whole concept of MDM on Android is very different than on iOS (which you saw already).

Take a look on these questions regarding email configuration. However, all of them are related to configuring it through the execution of code on device:

[Configuring a 3rd party email account in Android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116381/configuring-a-3rd-party-email-account-in-android-programmatically)

[How to successfully add account to android E-mail Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400786/how-to-successfully-add-account-to-android-e-mail-database)

[Android Email Programmatic Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821270/android-email-programmatic-setup)

Comment: Has there been a way to configure an app's settings in Android like in iOS with Configuration Profiles since this answer was posted?  In iOS you can just email users the profile file and it will update the app's settings when they open the file.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to set a user up remotely or setting up a number of users that will receive their devices straight from the shop - you can setup the users email and other setting on a phone and then download the smartswitch profile to an sd card (or other media) and then email that to the user to put onto their sd card to the import the preconfigured setting and account info to their phone. you can chose to just copy say the settings files, maybe even just the email setting. have a play. its a very useful tool.