# Configuring a 3rd party email account in Android programmatically

Tags: android

Is it possible to configure a 3rd party email account in Android programmatically. 
Is there any API for this?

Basically I am trying to create an app that would:

1. ask the user for email address and password
2. Verify the credentials. If everything is fine, the email account is automatically configured with the incoming and outgoing mail server details

The issue is that users don't find it easy remembering the server details etc.And our aim is to help our users set up their email accounts on their devices

Comment: @Lucifer, I want to know if there is any API for it. I tried searching for it, but could not find it :)

Comment: @ambit have you found any API ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a popular provider such as gmail, hotmail, aol etc then you will be able to do this but individual mail servers such as company emails etc have their own configurations and such which can be difficult to gauge programmatically.

As for how to implement a mail client, you can check out the source code for K9 mail. It is an excellent open source, full functional email client for android. It supports POP3, IMAP and Exchange accounts. You'll find everything you need to learn about making an android email app if you study its source. It's hosted on Github here:

https://github.com/k9mail/k-9

Here's the free app on the google play store:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9&hl=en

Comment: does it work well with company email address ? say like abc@xyz.org

Comment: I see no reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: Its cool if its working fine as since last few days i am facing some problems for sending email through my company email id.